# Pandas groupby, return rows of 1 column based on maximum values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In my data, I need to group by columns X,Y,Z and fill out the result code column.
The values will be filled from **code** column based on max value of either area or new_area column.

So for first group, code C has maximum area. In that case, all rows for that group should be C.
For the second group, since the max area is same, so checking the new_area column, the result should be code B.

I need to have these results in a separate column along with other columns as well.

The table in the pic will help clarify.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9VwE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple case of sorting then taking *first*

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""X,Y,Z,code,area,new_area,result_code
222 North St,Seattle,WA,A,200,600,C
222 North St,Seattle,WA,B,300,700,C
222 North St,Seattle,WA,C,400,750,C
222 North St,Seattle,WA,D,300,600,C
115 John St,Chicago,IL,A,200,250,B
115 John St,Chicago,IL,B,200,300,B
115 John St,Chicago,IL,C,50,100,B"""))

df = (df.sort_values(["X","Y","Z","area","new_area"], ascending=[True,True,True,False,False])
      .assign(result_code=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby(["X","Y","Z"])["code"].transform("first"))
      .sort_index()
     )

df = (df.sort_values(["X","Y","Z","area","new_area"], ascending=[True,True,True,False,False])
      .assign(result_code=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby(["X","Y","Z"])["code"].transform("first"))
      .sort_index()
     )
```

#### output

|  | X | Y | Z | code | area | new_area | result_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 222 North St | Seattle | WA | A | 200 | 600 | C |
| 1 | 222 North St | Seattle | WA | B | 300 | 700 | C |
| 2 | 222 North St | Seattle | WA | C | 400 | 750 | C |
| 3 | 222 North St | Seattle | WA | D | 300 | 600 | C |
| 4 | 115 John St | Chicago | IL | A | 200 | 250 | B |
| 5 | 115 John St | Chicago | IL | B | 200 | 300 | B |
| 6 | 115 John St | Chicago | IL | C | 50 | 100 | B |

Comment: result_code has to be a new column created. Can you modify your code to create this new column?

Comment: it is a new column....  look at `assign()` part,  no where do you find it in in put data...

Comment: for sake of convenience I've updated answer to use CSV instead of TSV

Comment: Thank you for the answer